# document.createElement fails for new window

Tags: javascript

I have two HTML files, FirstWindow and SecondWindow. FirstWindow has FirstWindowJS.js as its script and SecondWindow has SecondWindowJS.js as its script.

Through FirstWindowJS.js, I open SecondWindow.html. However, I am unable to create an element for it. Here's the code along with the problem -

FirstWindow.html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>FirstWindow</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="FirstWindowJS.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

SecondWindow.html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>SecondWindow</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="SecondWindowJS.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

FirstWindowJS.js

```
main();

function main()
{
    var myWindow = window.open("SecondWindow.html", "My Window", 
    "resizable=0,width=700,height=600");

    var e = myWindow.document.createElement("currentUserElement");
    e.setAttribute("id", "currentUserElement");
    e.setAttribute("value","John");
}
```

SecondWindowJS.js

```
main();

function main()
{
     var e = document.getElementById("currentUserElement"); 
     var value = e.getAttribute("value");
     console.log("value = "+value);
}
```

The error that I get in the SecondWindowJS.js is -

```
TypeError: e is null
```

Why is "e" null? What is the mistake?

Answer (score 3):

It's possible that the new window runs its JavaScript before the opener's script continues, but it's more likely that you can't use `getElementById` on an element that has not been appended to the document yet.

```
myWindow.document.body.appendChild(e);
```

Comment: I still get the error after doing this. I checked the logs and the new window's script runs after the first window's script, so I am not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

You create the element, but it doesn't look like you are adding it to the DOM. An element doesn't exist in the DOM until you explicitly add it using the [*parentNode*.appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild) method.

In your case it would look something like this, if you just want to add the element as the last element in your body-element:

```
function main()
{
    var myWindow = window.open("SecondWindow.html", "My Window", 
    "resizable=0,width=700,height=600");

    var e = myWindow.document.createElement("currentUserElement");
    e.setAttribute("id", "currentUserElement");
    e.setAttribute("value","John");
    // The element doesn't exist in the DOM until you explicitly add it
    myWindow.document.body.appendChild(e);
}
```

Comment: `myWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]` could be replaced with `myWindow.document.body`.

Comment: Same comment as the one above, I still get the error after doing this. I checked the logs and the new window's script runs after the first window's script, so I am not sure what the problem is.

Comment: @codeblue If you log the body element the first thing you do in your main-function for the second window, does it contain the added element?